# Vb6 TabStrip - Como visualizar os controles das TABs fora do escopo

Tags: visual-basic-6

Saudações a todos.

Minha área é C, mas preciso dar manutenção em um produto implementado em visual Basic 6 . Este produto é um configurador de um software em c, a função dele é apenas gerar um arquivo .ini para configuração do executável principal.

Preciso inserir alguns controles dentro das Tabs, mas quando abro o projeto somente a primeira TAB (de cima) fica visível durante a edição do projeto.

Gostaria de saber como fazer as TABS debaixo aparecerem para edição ou como tornar visível os controles das TABS debaixo para edição. A impressão que eu tive é que elas ficam como se fosse em camadas, e dependendo da TAB selecionada em tempo de execução esse controles das TABS são ocultados ou destacados, mas de fato não se é isso mesmo.

Se alguém tiver alguma idéia ou algum link de algum material sobre o assunto porque o pouco material que eu achei não sanou as minhas dúvidas.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow Roberto. Qual é o controle que tem essas "TABS" que você se refere? Por favor, poste um trecho do código que você já tem para termos uma ideia melhor do problema, sugiro que leia esse artigo da ajuda do site: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Vai na propriedade (Property Pages) da Tab. Na segunda guia (Tabs) você vai ter o botão Insert Tab com todas as suas propriedades (Index, Caption, Key, Tag, ToolTip...).

Comment: Deu certo Roberto Elias?